# All page height with position: fixed in Safari iOS

Tags: html, css, gpu, mobile-safari

I found a quirk in Safari on iOS. I have an element with `position: fixed` and I wanted to make sure it takes entire height, so I gave it `height: 9999px` (yeah, I know `100vh` is enough).

When there's scrollable content under it, Safari trims the bottom of the fixed element no matter what, even though it's supposed to be much taller in height.

Here's the snippet:

```css
body {
    background-color: orange;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.fixed {
    background-color: #444;
    height: 9999px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.content {
    height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Pointer Events</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="fixed">
        I'm an element with position: fixed, scroll me
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        I'm a big block of text
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Soon after, I found a fix for that. Adding any `transform` to the fixed element makes it work correctly and the element now takes entire height. My understanding is that it makes the GPU work and rendering is improved.

I created this post to understand the issue better - is this a known bug? Is there a known reason why it happens?